# Jenkins build triggers not waiting on child's child to be finished

Tags: jenkins

[image]
I have a Jenkins job that runs A first and then B.
However, A needs to wait until all its children are finished.
(A1, A1-a, A1-a1, A2, A2-a, A2-a1)

However, somehow my Jenkins runs "B" as soon as both A1 and A2 are done; regardless of A1-a, A1-a1, A2-a, A2-a1 are done.

A1 and A2 have following build trigger options:

[image]

Is it because all are set to "never"?? 
Can someone tell me what needs to be changed?

Thank you